# Trap instruction: why must the program counter and processor status register be changed atomically?

Tags: kernel-mode, program-counter, status-register

I came across the following problem on a previous exam from my operating systems class.

Consider an architecture in which the TRAP instruction has two effects: to load a predefined value of the Processor Status Register (PCR), which contains the user/kernel mode bit, saving the value of the Program Counter (PC) to a special Save PC register and loading apredefined value into the PC. Explain why loading a new value for the PCR without also changing the PC in the same instruction cycle would be unsafe.

I know that the PCR would be set to kernel mode with memory management off. Is it unsafe because the PC is still in the user program? If so where could it go wrong? If not why is it unsafe? Why would changing the PC first also be unsafe?

Comment: By "in the same instruction cycle" you mean using the same instruction rather than two separate instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: there is no reason to assume that "memory management" is turned "off" by loading the new processor status; in fact, in the CPUs in my experience that would not happen. But that is not relevant to this answer.

We're executing in user mode and a TRAP instruction is fetched. The program counter is then (let's say) pointing to the instruction after TRAP.

Now the processor executes the TRAP. It loads the new processor status, which switches the CPU to kernel mode. Assume this does not in itself inhibit device interrupts.

NOW... a device interrupts.  The hardware or software mechanism saves the processor status (=kernel mode) and program counter (=the user-mode address of the instruction after TRAP).  The device interrupt service routine does its thing and executes a return from interrupt to restore program counter and processor status.  We can't resume "half-way through the TRAP instruction" - the only thing that can happen is that we start to execute the instruction that PC points to, i.e., we're executing the instruction after the TRAP but in kernel mode.

The exact problem depends on the system architecture:

If the kernel address map is a superset of the user address map (typical on OSes where user space is half the total address space) then we're executing user-provided code in kernel mode, which is at least a serious privilege problem, and may cause us to fail by page faulting when we can't handle it.

If the kernel address map doesn't include user space (frequently the case on systems with limited virtual address size) then this is equivalent to taking wild jump into the kernel.

The summary is that you need both the processor status and program counter to define "where you are in execution", and they both need to be saved/updated together; or in other words, no change of control (such as an interrupt) can be permitted in the middle.